# A link should stay pressed until you click another one

Tags: html, jquery, css

I was playing around with html and css. But I couldn't make it work.

What I want: the first link/tab should appear pressed when you open the site. It should change to unpressed when you click another link. There is a green line on the top. I want it to change its color when you press a navigation tab/link at the same time.

```css
body {}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid #8dc63f;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #8dc63f;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  content: '+';
}

a:hover::after {
  background: #cbda29;
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link4">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="link1">
  <h1>Hello. I am Link1. If you see this the first link/button should stay pressed/clicked/lightgreen background until
    you click another link. The top line "border-top" should change its color as well if you click a link.
  </h1>
</div>
<div id="link2">
  <h2>Oh hello i am the second link you clicked. The first button shouldn't be clicked anymore. Now link2 should appear
    as a clicked button.
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use JS? Without JS top line will not change color properly

Comment: there is nothing that can appear as "pressed" in your code, and at any time.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the nav link, give it a class, eg "active", and remove that class from any other "active" links.

With the correct css, you can give the header the same "active" class

```
a.active::after {
  background-color:#cbda29; 
}
header.active {
  border-top-color:#cbda29; 
}
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$("nav > ul > li > a").click(function() {
    $("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("header").css("border-top-color", $(this).data("color"))
});
```

```css
a.active::after {
  background-color:#cbda29; 
}
header.active {
  border-top-color:#cbda29; 
}


body {}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid #8dc63f;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #8dc63f;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  content: '+';
}

a:hover::after {
  background: #cbda29;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#link1" data-color="red">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link2" data-color="blue">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link3" data-color="purple">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link4" data-color="green">Link4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="link1">
  <h1>Hello. I am Link1. If you see this the first link/button should stay pressed/clicked/lightgreen background until you click another link. The top line "border-top" should change its color as well if you click a link. </h1>
</div>
<div id="link2">
  <h2>Oh hello i am the second link you clicked. The first button shouldn't be clicked anymore. Now link2 should appear as a clicked button.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats awesome. Thank you. Is there a possibility to change the color of the line at the top when you click a link?

Comment: Already included that with `header.active {  border-top-color:#cbda29; }` - did you want it a different colour depending on the link?

Comment: Exactly.With every clicked link (navigation) the border-color should change at the same time.

Comment: Right, that's what it's doing - can you explain what it's not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: The border-top-color should get its individual color with every single click on the "tabs". It changes its color but its stays and doesn't switch back.

I want link1 to get its own border-top-color in header. And i want link2 to get its own border color. But they stay and do now switch back and forth. I want them to change simultaneously with the click on each "tab".

Comment: Switch back to what?  You'll need to be clearer.  How does it know which colour to use?

Comment: I've updated so that the top border changes to a colour designated on the link - not sure this is an ideal solution, but there's no indication in the question (that it should change to a different colour per link) or comments on how it knows which colour to change to, so this is just one solution.

Comment: Link1 (tab) should turn orange when you click it. The backgroundcolor of the tab. And the same time border-top should turn orange.

Link2 if i click link2 the backgroundcolor of the tab should turn into red at the same time the border-top-color should get the SAME color.

And when i click link3 the backgroundcolor turns into black and at the same time the border-top-color changes into black as well.


BUT.. the border-top-color should only stay the same color UNTIL you press another link.

And when u first open the site. LINK1 should be pressed to see that you are on the main page.

Comment: Pretty sure you can go with what's been provided by myself (and the other answer), both of which answer the question as asked, and apply those changes - eg changing the colour from red to orange really shouldn't be beyond you.

Answer (score 0):

> The first link/tab should appear pressed when you open the site.

Below example will make the first tab a different color on page load. I have added a `active` class to li to change color. During click of the menu items you should remove/add a class eg: `active` to the `li` to change the color of that particular menu button.

Use the below JS to toggle class names

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
   $('nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
})
```

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
   $('nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $('header').css('border-top-color', 'red');
})
```

```css
body {}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid #8dc63f;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #8dc63f;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  content: '+';
}

a:hover::after {
  background: #cbda29;
}

nav li.active a::after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>




  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#link4">Link4</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>



<div id="link1">
  <h1>Hello. I am Link1. If you see this the first link/button should stay pressed/clicked/lightgreen background until you click another link. The top line "border-top" should change its color as well if you click a link. </h1>
</div>

<div id="link2">
  <h2>Oh hello i am the second link you clicked. The first button shouldn't be clicked anymore. Now link2 should appear as a clicked button.</h2>
</div>
```

**Update after comment**

> Every button should get its individual background-color when you
> click/press it. The backgroundcolor should get the same color as the
> border-color.

```js
var prevClass = 'link1';
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
   /*$('nav li').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $('header').css('border-top-color', 'red');*/
   var newClass = $(this).attr('id');
   
   if(prevClass) {
      $('header').removeClass(prevClass);
   }
   $('header').addClass(newClass);
   prevClass = newClass;
})
```

```css
body {}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 5px solid #8dc63f;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  top: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 500px;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #8dc63f;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

nav ul li a::before {
  content: '+';
}

a:hover::after {
  background: #cbda29;
}

header.link1 nav li a#link1::after {
  background: red;
}
header.link2 nav li a#link2::after {
  background: yellow;
}
header.link3 nav li a#link3::after {
  background: purple;
}

header.link4 nav li a#link4::after {
  background: blue;
}

header.link1 {
  border-top-color: red;
}
header.link2 {
  border-top-color: yellow;
}
header.link3 {
  border-top-color: purple;
}
header.link4 {
  border-top-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class='link1'>




  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a id="link1" href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a id="link2" href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a id="link3" href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a id="link4" href="#link4">Link4</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>



<div id="link1">
  <h1>Hello. I am Link1. If you see this the first link/button should stay pressed/clicked/lightgreen background until you click another link. The top line "border-top" should change its color as well if you click a link. </h1>
</div>

<div id="link2">
  <h2>Oh hello i am the second link you clicked. The first button shouldn't be clicked anymore. Now link2 should appear as a clicked button.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. But when you click "Link2" it should turn into red or another color of choice and the first button should become green again. And the line at the top should change its color as well.

Comment: @Christopher Click event handler added, plz check. For header color change you need to change the `border`. I will try to add it

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The border color should change to its individual color with every tablink you clicked. How to do that?

Comment: When you click a link the border color should change to the backgroundcolor of the linktab. And it should change with every other link click.

Comment: Where is the border, I do see any border in button. The header top border color will change with the above code

Comment: border-top-color in header should change to its INDIVIDUAL color with every pressed link in the navigation.

Comment: You click link2 and the backgroundcolor turns into red. The border-top-color in header should change to another color. And when you click link1 again the border-top-color changes, too.

Comment: Do you know what i mean? When you click a link the border color in header should have its own color and it switches if you press another link. It should not stay one color. It should change with every click.

Comment: You mean all the buttons have different color and the button and header color should be same?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Every button should get its individual background-color when you click/press it. The backgroundcolor should get the same color as the border-color.

Comment: For example i click link1 the backgroundcolor changes into purple. The border color in header should turn purple, too. When i click link2 the backgroundcolor of the "tab" turns yellow AND the border-top-color in header changes to yellow too. At the same time. And so on.

Comment: it's no longer troubleshooting, it's a supply of free code with specifications that change every time!